# combinatorial problem with counting student attendance

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

How can i solve that problem?

Input:
s - string (n <= 100 000), which includes the following letters:

a for absent
l for late
p for present

if consecutive letters 'aaa' then Output: student is not allowed to the exam
if  string have more than 4 'L' then Output: student is not allowed to the exam

else - student is allowed to the exam.

**EXAMPLE:**

> Input: PPPPPLLLL 
>  Output: student is not allowed to the exam
>
> Input: PLPLPPPAAA 
>  Output: student is not allowed to the exam
>
> Input: APLPLLPPAP 
>   Output: student is allowed to the exam

i need a combinatorial formula. but how to apply it and which one?

Comment: Re: "i need a combinatorial formula": What makes you say that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reading the requirement to be that more than 4 Ls anywhere in the string prevents the student from taking the exam - they don't have to be consecutive. Also, I'm assuming all upper-case characters.

The shortest Java solution would, I think, be this:

```
static boolean canTakeExam(String s)
{
    return !s.contains("AAA") && s.replaceAll("[^L]", "").length() < 4;
}
```

But a more efficient implementation would be:

```
static boolean canTakeExam(String s)
{
    for(int i=0, ca=0, cl=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(c == 'A')
        {
            if(++ca == 3) return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(c == 'L' && ++cl == 4) return false;
            ca = 0;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and the most naïve solution is to iterate through all the characters in the worst `O(n)` complexity - actually, I am not aware of any better solution. The `100'000` iterations are nothing that Java cannot handle.

```
int consecutiveA = 0;                                          // Absent counter
int consecutiveL = 0;                                          // Late counter

boolean flag = true;

for (char ch: s.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {                 // Iterate through the chars
    if (ch == 'a') {                                           // Checks the absent
        consecutiveL = 0;
        consecutiveA++;
    } else if (ch == 'l') {                                    // Checks the late
        consecutiveA = 0;
        consecutiveL++;
    } else {                                                   // Or else reset counters
        consecutiveA = 0;
        consecutiveL = 0;
    }
    if (consecutiveA == 3 || consecutiveL == 4) {              // If the condition is met
        System.out.println("Student is not allowed to exam."); // Print it out
        flag = false;                                          // Sets the flag
        break;                                                 // And leave the cycle
    }
}

if (flag) {                                                   
    System.out.println("Student is allowed to exam.");
}
```

Note the key part is also the usage of `break` keyword which makes the looping stop and leaves the `for-cycle`. This could save the checking of lots of characters onward and avoids printing `"Student is not allowed to exam."` more than once.

The problematic part might be if the letters will be a mix of the upper-lower case (my snippet). If you are sure only one case would appear, the `String::toLowerCase()` might be omitted.

Comment: I believe there's a bug here.  If my attendence record is ALALA or LLALL, I get barred from the exam.  I don't think that matches the specification.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: A good point! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot, I fixed it.

Comment: I don't think you did fix the bug.  I think you've just introduced a new bug.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: Hmpf, another attempt? I think it should work now.

Comment: Yeah, that looks better.  Here, have an upvote.